# Wordpress "Error establishing a database connection" only when using nginx proxy

Tags: wordpress, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a wordpress site that works fine by itself, but when I am trying to put it behind the nginx proxy (proxy_pass), I am getting the "Error establishing a database connection" everytime.

```
location /blog/ {
  proxy_pass https://blog.example.com/;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The issue was

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

The https://blog.example.com/ is a virtual host and nginx sends a request to it, as the request would be to https://example.com/blog, confusing the virtual hosts logic.   The error itself is unrelated to the cause of the issue.  There was a broken wordpress site on that (example.com/blog) url already.

The solution:

```
proxy_set_header Host blog.example.com;
```

this would correctly get the correct site from virtual host, then the result is sent to the proxy server that would convert it to example.com/blog